# Idiomatic way of extending keymap for inserting unicode symbols?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, unicode, characters, insert-char

I often find myself needing to insert Unicode characters that have no default binding in `iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map`, i.e., characters that can't be inserted using <kbd>C-x 8</kbd> followed by one or more letters/punctuation characters.

To add bindings to the <kbd>C-x 8</kbd> keymap, I usually

1. define a custom command for inserting a given Unicode character, such as:

   ```el
   (defun ucs-rightwards-arrow ()
     "Insert unicode symbol: →"
     (interactive)
     (insert-char #x2192))
   ```
2. add a binding for this command to the map via

   ```el
   (define-key iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map (kbd "a") 'ucs-rightwards-arrow)
   ```

Since the <kbd>C-x 8</kbd> keymap really only pairs key bindings with single characters I'm wondering:

**Q:** Is there a more light-weight/idiomatic way of extending the <kbd>C-x 8</kbd> keymap?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no need to define a command to bind a unicode char:

```
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map "a" [?α])
```

binds α to <kbd>C-x 8 a</kbd>. While

```
(define-key 'iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map (kbd "M-s") [?ς])
```

binds ς to <kbd>C-x 8 M-s</kbd>.

Comment: The array can be swapped out for a string btw, that would make it a byte shorter.

Answer (score 4):

Library [`ucs-cmds.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/ucs-cmds.el) can help.

It provides a macro, `ucsc-make-commands`, for quickly *creating a set of commands* that insert Unicode characters. You provide a regexp to it, which is matched against all Unicode character names (in `ucs-names`). An insertion
command is created for each of the characters whose name matches. (The command names are essentially the same as the char names - see below.)

Sample command creations:

```el
 (ucsc-make-commands "^math") ; Math symbols
 (ucsc-make-commands "latin") ; Latin alphabet characters
 (ucsc-make-commands "arabic")
 (ucsc-make-commands "^cjk")  ; Chinese, Japanese, Korean characters
 (ucsc-make-commands "^box drawings ")
 (ucsc-make-commands "^greek [a-z]+ letter") ; Greek characters
 (ucsc-make-commands "\\(^hangul\\|^circled hangul\\|^parenthesized hangul\\)")
```

This is the doc string:

```
ucsc-make-commands is a Lisp macro in `ucs-cmds.el'.

(ucsc-make-commands REGEXP)

Create commands to insert Unicode characters whose names match REGEXP.
Letter case is ignored for matching.

The set of char names used is taken from `ucs-names'.  There are
*many* such chars, so consider using a tighter regexp to limit the
number of commands created.

The commands created have the same names as the chars they insert,
except that `SPC' chars in the character names are replaced by
hyphens (`-'), and the command names are lowercase.
```

If you wanted to bind the commands you create to keys in a systematic way, then you could easily create a macro based on the code of `ucsc-make-commands` that both creates the commands you want and binds them. Macro `ucsc-make-commands` just iterates over all of the Unicode cars and creates commands for those whose names match the `REGEXP` argument.

During an iteration you have access to the character name and its code point. Figure out a convenient regular mapping of either code points or char names to keys, and your macro can add the appropriate `define-key`s in addition to the command `defun`s.

---

The library also provides a command, `ucsc-insert`, that can replace vanilla command
`insert-char`. The behavior and code of `ucsc-insert` are identical to those of
`insert-char` except for what happens when you use a negative prefix argument:

1. It acts as if the prefix-arg value was positive.  So a value of
   -3 inserts three copies of the character, just as 3 does.
2. In addition to inserting the character, it defines a command
   that you can use thereafter to insert that character.  You can
   use a prefix argument with that command to insert multiple
   copies of the given character.

This gives you a command that is tailor-made to insert a given
Unicode character.  You can then bind the command to a key
sequence, effectively adding Unicode characters to your keyboard.

Whenever `insert-char` does anything (it does nothing for a
negative prefix arg), `ucsc-insert` does the same thing.  Because
of this, you can bind `ucsc-insert` to `C-x 8 RET` as
a replacement for `insert-char`:

```el
(define-key global-map [remap insert-char] 'ucsc-insert)
```

If you need only a few such commands for inserting particular
Unicode characters, then using `ucsc-insert` to define them is
sufficiently convenient. If you need a lot of such commands then macro `ucsc-make-commands` is your friend.

Comment: Thanks, `ucsc-insert` looks like it could help cover my use cases. Defining new commands interactively (via `M--` `M-x` `ucsc-insert` `RET` `#x2190` `RET`) works fine, but when I try to execute them (after binding them via `(define-key iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map (kbd "b") 'left-arrow)`) I get "Wrong type argument: wholenump, nil". Could you give an example of how `ucsc-insert` can be used to programmatically define a binding for a specific Unicode character?

Comment: Right you are! There was a bug here. Fixed now on Emacs Wiki [`ucs-cmds.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/ucs-cmds.el). Should be mirrored to MELPA within 24 hours. **Thx.**

Comment: Glad I was able to help you find and fix a bug :) I can now define and bind commands for inserting specific Unicode symbols via `(ucsc-insert #x2192 -1) (define-key ctl-x-map (kbd "8 a") 'right-arrow)`, which is definitely more concise than my original approach. I need to ask, however, if this is the *intended* way of using `ucsc-insert` to define commands for Unicode symbols that persist across sessions? I have a feeling it might not be, because it causes Emacs to insert characters for which I am defining custom commands into the `*scratch*` buffer at start-up...

Comment: The intended use of `ucsc-insert` is for it to behave just like `ucs-insert`, aka `insert-char`, unless you use a negative prefix arg - *it always inserts a char*. If you do not want to insert a char, but just want to define a command to insert a char, then you could use macro `ucsc-make-commands`. But you are right (again) that it would be good to have a function that just defines a single command. So I added function (command) `ucsc-define-char-insert-cmd`. E.g.: `(ucsc-define-char-insert-cmd 8592)` defines the command and returns its symbol, `left-arrow`. Please try the latest. Thx.

Comment: Thanks, will try it out once the update makes it into MELPA!

Comment: Pardon my n00b question, but I have inserted this `(ucsc-make-commands "^greek [a-z]+ letter")` into my .emacs file, and it errors. if I add `require "ucs-cmds"` it does not find the file. Plus, even when I do, It's not really clear to me how to actually type the Greek keys (or whatever) or if I have to make additional keymappings.

Comment: As always, to `require` a library you need to put its directory in your `load-path` - e.g., `(add-to-list 'load-path "/PATH/TO/MY/DIR/")`. `ucsc-make-commands` defines a command for each such char (in this case, greek letters). Just bind whichever of those commands you want to whichever keys you want - see the Emacs manual, node [Key Bindings](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Key-Bindings.html) and its subnodes.